# Using ng-click with ng-repeat to create a filter menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to create my filter menu, with all the modalities inside my timeline.

```
<a ng-click="filterModality = {entry_team.name: '{{modality}}'}" ng-repeat="modality in modalities">{{modality}}</a>

<!-- 
Output 
<a ng-click="filterModality = {entry_team.name: 'Atletismo'}" ng-repeat="modality in modalities">Atletismo</a>
-->


<a ng-click="filterModality = {entry_team.name: 'Atletismo'}">Atletismo</a>
```

The ng-repeat doesn't work but the same output doing manually worked fine.
I'm using AngularJS 1.2.9 (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing interpolation with two-way binding. Also, you are setting an object reference in the ng-repeat scope which is probably creating a new object reference in that scope which then masks the reference of the same name in the parent scope.

Try defining your object in the parent scope using `filterModality = {}` and then just change the property value in the ng-click instead of changing the object reference.

```
<a ng-click="filterModality['entry_team.name'] = modality" ng-repeat="modality in modalities">{{modality}}</a>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :( The click action don't changes anything

Comment: Even if I edit the ng-click to ng-click="filterModality = 'Atletismo'" it doesn't work. The problem isn't the string modality. I think it is because the ng-repeat. When I do it manually, without ng-repeat, it works.

Comment: @thiagonzalez, ng-repeat creates a new scope that prototypically inherits from the parent scope, so this should work unless you're defining `filterModality` in the ng-repeat scope... and now that I typed that, I think that's exactly what the ng-click is doing. So, instead, make sure filterModality is defined as an object (`{}`) in the parent scope and then change your code to update the property instead of overwriting the object reference. See my update.

Comment: man, you are the best! That last example worked perfectly! Thank you very much!